# Pickled model instance's Django version 3.0.3 does not match the current version 3.0.7

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, caching, pickle

When upgrading Django version from Django 3.0.3 to 3.0.7. I get this error.

```
RuntimeWarning: Pickled model instance's Django version 3.0.3 does not match the current version 3.0.7.
value = pickle.loads(value)
```

Is there any way to solve this issue to continue deployment without downtime

Comment: Do you cache model instances? You may flush cache. You can check the Django commit that adds pickle version checking: https://github.com/django/django/commit/42736ac